# C# Nearest Low Value in array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I need to get the nearest value in an array, however, i need it to be the low option not high
eg.

```
double[] array = new double[4] { 1.0, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8 };

double NewValue = 1.4;
```

Result should be 1.0, not 1.5 which would be the nearest

Comment: So you want the closest that is lower than the given number?

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: I guess you have tried something, did you? It would be nice if you could show that. It would be easier to help you understand where you got it wrong.

Comment: NewValue is the number which you search the nbearest value for?

Comment: What if the number is less than the minimum value in the array?

Comment: Use divide and conquer principle on a sorted array. Start at `index/2` where `index = array.length()`. Check if the value you want is in the first half or the second half of the array. Use the correct sub-array and keep repeating till you find your desired value. Be careful with the boundaries, if you reach `index == 0` or `index == array.Length() - 1` then you need to break your loop. Try it yourself, don't expect people to code for you.

Comment: A good place to start is to think how *you* came up with 1.0 as the answer, and then from there try to write code that follows the same mental steps you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below will work, using standard LINQ:

```
var nearestBelow = newValue - array.Where(n => n <= newValue)
                                  .Min(n => newValue - n);
```

Answer (score 0):

In other words you want the maximum value of all elements less or equal to NewValue ?

```
double nearest = array.Where(x => x <= NewValue).Max<double>();
```

Comment: unless all the values are larger?

Comment: @o_weisman: in that case there is no answer if I read the question correctly. So that is not a problem.

Comment: Seems a shame to scan twice: `var nearest = array.Aggregate((a, t) => a = (t < NewValue) ? Math.Max(a, t) : a);`